# XAML tooltips are being clipped

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip, clipping, z-order

I am trying to make a WPF app (regular Windows app, not XBAP or Silverlight).
I want the main app window to support transparency, and show through the desktop below.

But when I specify ToolTip text on a Button, the ToolTip appears *beneath* (z-order) the main window!

I have a screenshot where:
* Another app overlapps and blocks view of the partially transparent main window.
* The tooltip from my button appears in front of the other app.
* Where the tooltip is not in front of the other app, it is *behind* the partial transparency.

I read elsewhere that this is a known problem with the WPF engine for 32-bit XP and does not occur in Vista.

What I am looking for is a fix/workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok- here's what I found as a workaround:

The problem with ToolTips goes away when the window is also made TopMost.

But I don't want my window to be topmost, so I only do it when my window has keyboard focus:

```
private void Window_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Topmost = true;
}

private void Window_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Topmost = false;
}
```

Then I use a binding to enable each ToolTip only when my window is Topmost:

```
ToolTipService="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=Topmost}"
```

This turns off the ToolTip except when it works right.
Don't really need tooltips when my window isn't in focus anyway.

Only annoying thing now is that the on/off binding has to be done on every element that defines a Tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Try the .SetValue(Canvas.ZIndex, 100) method on the UIElement you want on top. (I used 100, only to force the element to the top)

Comment: Doesn't work when I'm not using a Canvas to render the window.

Comment: Using a Canvas has nothing to do with the Canvas.ZIndex DependencyProperty (un-intuitive as that sounds)

Answer (score 0):

This is a know problem of WIndows XP and WPF (e.g. see here [on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=431170)).

You can avoid the problem by *not using a layered window* (use one with a frame). I think another solution would be to set the whole window *TopMost=true*, but for me, that's not a very good solution and I'm not sure about that.

I don't know if MS is tackling this issue, because I think it's quite deep in the graphic layer of XP.

Comment: My impression is that its not in the XP graphics layer at all - it looks more like WPF draws an entire second desktop layer atop the native XP (Win32) graphics - but clips it to fit where WPF should be 'visible'.  This is the way early 3D and movie accellerators worked if they were 'windowed'.

Comment: Well, that I don't know. But I know it's not just a clipping problem. Even if the Tooltip would be entirely inside the WPF- Window Area, it can happen that the Tooltips are behind the application. You can see that with a tool like Snoop, or if the Tooltip is long enough to go over the borders of the WPF-Window.